# Define a second name for a function

Tags: functions

I'm working with an own package of functions. During development I noticed, that my naming scheme is not that clever; for example some of my functions are starting with capital letters. But I have several files working with that package, that I would like to be able to use further on with as few as possible. So my idea is, to write a small package named `loadOldNams`or something like that, providing the old function names additionally.

Therefore I'm facing the following problem:

Having a function with my new name - for simplification just `f`, e.g.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
f[x_, y_] := x^2 y^2;
f::usage = "A test usage text";
```

I would like to define a function having the old name (say `g`), such that all cases 'g[x], g[x,y]`and the`::usage`also work with`g`.

Just `f=g;` or `f:=g;` won't work, so

How do I get a function with the name `g` doing exactly the same as `f` (just having another name)?

Comment: Luckily, this very same question was asked just a couple of days ago and has a very nice answer that would be perfect for your case :) Let me know if it isn't (and why) and we can reopen this one with the specific problem.

Comment: Wow! I tried to search some words, but didn't come up with those; actually your posted Question does even more that I wanted. With the mentioned Operator that even gets nicer than i thought. It's perfect - and you were very fast :)

Comment: You're welcome :)